# If everything in JavaScript is an object then why does the 'typeof' operator return 'function' for 'Object'?

Tags: javascript, function, object

From some source, I have learned that everything in JavaScript is an object. Then why does the *typeof* operator return *function* for Object?

```
console.log(typeof Object); 
//function
```

Comment: The same reason that if you pointed at a factory that made cars and asked me what it is, I'd tell you it is a factory (and I wouldn't tell you it was a car)

Answer (score 1):

Because `Object` is the constructor for an object.